# csvkit/in2csv: AttributeError: 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'defined_names'

Tags: homebrew, csvkit

I have installed `csvkit` with Homebrew, but when running `in2csv foo.xlsx > foo.csv`, I'm always getting this error message:

> AttributeError: 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'defined_names'

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by reinstalling `csvkit` with `pip`.

```
brew uninstall csvkit
pip install csvkit
```